# Converting a matrix of integers into strings

Tags: string, matlab, matrix, rename

Let's say i have a few matrices of some numbers, and the names of those matrices are also numbers (1, 2, 3, 4), and also there is an array of string values. For example it's like ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']. Is there any way to rename the '1' matrix to 'A', '2' matrix to 'B' and etc?

I'm searching for something like this:

```
for i=1,4
    rename i to c{1,i}
end
```

Comment: As pointed out already, you cannot use *only* numbers in the name of a matrix. Moreover, `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']` is the string 'ABCD', not an "array of strings".

Answer (score 2):

First, you can't name a matrix with a number in Matlab.
Second, say you have `old_names` and `new_names` as cell arrays, for example:

```
 A=1; B=2; C=3; D=4;
 old_names={'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'};
 new_names={'AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD'};
```

Then you can play with something like this:

```
for n = 1:numel(new_names)
    eval([new_names{n} '=' old_names{n}]);  
end
```

Comment: Thank you. But it seems that i didn't explain my problem properly.
Imagine, i have an array of string values. and i have a bunch of matrices. How can i rename all those matrices with the string values of my array?
For example: The Cell Array is ['Name 1', 'Name 2'...], and i have matrices A, B, C, ... etc. How to rename matrix A to 'Name 1', matrix B to 'Name 2' and so on, using the command 'for'.